# Share user messages from my app to twitter

Tags: twitter, share, tweets

In my app, I am designing to allow user share messages to twitter. But those messages could already exceeded the 140 character constraint put on tweets, what will be the best way to work around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't work around the limit. If the 140 characters are exceeded twitter would not accept the message. I suggest you use a tweet-shortener like I do for my app.

What it basically does is if  the number of tweets => 140, strip it in half, create a html page containing the full tweet, send back the shortened tweet and the link to the app, then paste it.

But there are already third party tweet-shorteners available so you can try out any one.

http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=tweet+shortener
http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=tweet+longer

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the standard here is to create a shortened URL to the full version of the message to put at the end of the tweet, then fill the remaining space with as much of the message you can fit in 140 characters (with option trailing ellipsis). So, like:

"This is my message I want to share, and it is really lon... http://my.shrturl.com/aJdD"

Also, take a look at TwitLonger maybe? http://www.twitlonger.com/